# Bootstrap theme for webmin display half page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webmin, webmin-module-development

I am using bootstrap theme for webmin, It is working fine with chrome but when I moved to Firefox the webmin pages are displaying on half of screen, what might be the problem.
suggest me the changes.enter image description here

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer and author of [Authentic Theme](https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme) for *Webmin/Usermin/Virtualmin/Cloudmin.*

My theme actually works fine in *Firefox* as well. You are welcome to try it.

## **Authentic Theme**

> *Webmin/Usermin/Virtualmin/Cloudmin* theme based on Bootstrap and Font Awesome hat is made with love. It uses *CodeMirror* to highlight config files and show line numbers, when editing manually and *DataTables* to add advanced interaction controls to modules' tables. Theme runs using latest releases of dependent software (mentioned above), supporting all in-built modules (even ancient ones) and third-party modules, including *ConfigServer Security & Firewall*.

## **Features**

- **Autocomplete** that lets you very quickly and effectively navigate through items in *left menu*, items of *currently opened* module in *Webmin*,  items for *currently selected domain* and list of *all available virtual domains/machines* in *Virtualmin/Cloudmin* module
- **Hotkeys** for quicker access/control. `Alt+S` for focusing on search field; `Alt+R` for refreshing currently opened module; `Alt+W` switching to *Webmin*; `Alt+V` switching to *Virtualmin*; `Alt+C` switching to *Cloudmin* and *double* `Shift` to prematurely dismiss right page loader
- Extended support for **ConfigServer Security & Firewall**, with integrated *search* and *filter* features
- **Code highlight** with *line numbers*, when editing configuration files manually
- Ability to embed **custom** *logo*, *styles* and *scripts*
- Unprecedentedly **convenient and complete navigation**, with no difference among desktop/mobile versions
- *Dismissable* page **loader**
- Basic **screen-saver** effect, after 2 minutes of inactivity

## **Video Screencast**

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_oy3qX2GXo